# MySQL how do I make GRANTs work for roles? They work only for users

Tags: mysql

If I grant SELECT to user I don't have a problem but if I grant SELECT to role and then grant role to user SELECT query doesn't work even though SHOW GRANTS for 'user' using 'role' shows that user has privilege to select

--as root

```
create role 'seller';
grant select on pharmacy.sells to 'seller';
create user 'seller1'@'localhost' identified by '1';
grant 'seller' to 'seller1'@'localhost'
```

--now as seller1

```
select * from pharmacy.sells

--Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user 'seller1'@'localhost' for table 'sells'

show grants for 'seller1'@'localhost' using 'seller'

--GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `seller1`@`localhost`

--GRANT SELECT ON `pharmacy`.`sells` TO `seller1`@`localhost`

--GRANT `seller`@`%` TO `seller1`@`localhost`
```

--as root

```
grant select on pharmacy.sells to 'seller1'@'localhost'
```

--as seller 1

```
select * from pharmacy.sells
```

--it works

--show grants shows the same thing

Comment: Do you have MySQL v8?

Comment: Yep, just downloaded yesterday from official site